# How to make one-page React app work in multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, create-react-app, session-cookies

We have a One-Page React application that is loaded from a link in another application. This other application provides URL parameters that are used to set cookies and fetch other data objects.

The problem is - the agents using this app tend to open multiple tabs for multiple separate data objects.

When this is done:

1. First tab opens with data from first client
2. Second tab opens with data from second client
3. First tab now has data from second client

I believe this is due to cookies that are getting overwritten. We use JWT for auth, and I am wondering if there is a way to support this? The apps all operate from the root path '/'.

What would be the best approach to correct this?